# How to insert a logic statement in keras functional API like that of a decision tree?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Suppose the following network

```
#sub model 1
i= Input()
x=Dense(i)
x=Dense(x)  #output [N times 1] array
```

However, at this step, one apply a function

```
f([N times 1]) #return True or False
```

such that, if f() returned 1 then

```
#sub model 2
y1=concentrate(Input, x) # i.e. Input and [N times 1] 
y1=Dense(y1)            
# notice that it's this dependence of the result from the previous network, 
#i.e. [N times 1] made the importance of training the model as a whole.
```

and if f() returned 0 then

```
#sub model 3
y1=Dense(Input)
y1=Dense(y1)
```

Like a Decision tree, but with the logic specified by user as a function f().

Question:

1. How to build such a network and being trained as a whole?
2. (**Resolved**, kept here to main a picture of the logics in the training process) Suppose that 1 was achieved, but if one wanted to attache a specific trained model to sub model 1, i.e. to utilize the trained parameters in `sub_model_1=Model(i,x)` into the network at the start of the training. How to achieve such "modular training"?

**Explanation of the logic behind question 1 and question 2**: One might think why not just build 3 neural networks and then define a function to connect them after being trained? As explained before, the dependence in sub model 2 was one of such reasons. However, it might be helpful to train the sub modules individuality, then fuse them into a complete model to train them together. This could potentially save the required training time in the order of square root, thus the Question 2.

**Updates on question 1**: One of such solution might be [create new layer via subclass](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/). However, that would require modification of all the used layers and the final layers. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: i don't understand, do you need to calculate the condtion at runtime or only when you are instantiating the model?

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow Basically, yes.